# html5: Adding a text below an image

Tags: html

I am new to HTML programming.
Please refer to the code below:

```
<div data-role="content" data-mini="true" >
  <div class="content-primary">
    <input type="image" src="images/mobile.png" style="width:100px; padding:5px; background:#fff; border:1px solid #999;" value="Input" type="image" onclick="mobileClicked()" data-role="none" />
    <span style="clear:both">Mobile</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*All i want is to get the text below the image.*

Comment: looks like ur value attribute is not closed correcttly

Comment: @ecco88: I have corrected it . Still i want the text to appear just below the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways that you can achieve this; If you are not married to using a `span` tag, one possibility is to change it to a `p` tag (jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tuanderful/WcU2M/ ) This allows you to even remove the `clear: both`

```
<div data-role="content" data-mini="true" >
    <div class="content-primary">
    <input type="image" src="images/mobile.png" style="width:100px; padding:5px; background:#fff; border:1px solid #999;" value="Input type=image" onclick="mobileClicked()" data-role="none" />
    <p style="">Mobile</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

If you stick with your current structure, I notice you have a `clear: both` on the caption... I'll add `float: left` to both the caption as well as the input.

```
<div data-role="content" data-mini="true" >
<div class="content-primary">
<input type="image" src="images/mobile.png" style="width:100px; padding:5px; background:#fff; border:1px solid #999;float: left" value="Input type=image" onclick="mobileClicked()" data-role="none" />
<span style="float: left; clear:both">Mobile</span> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Tuanderful, can u please tell if i can get a collective element of image & text ? Also, i want to place 4 images(with text) in 2 X 2 matrix type appearance in an mobile Safari(HTML)

Comment: I don't think there is an element that combines image and text... but we can build off the HTML that you had earlier to produce the following: http://jsfiddle.net/tuanderful/WcU2M/3/

Comment: In the updated fiddle, you'll notice that I added a container for the content divs. Divs naturally clear each other, so I created a CSS rule to float them. Finally, the container div is wide enough to hold 2 content divs across - subsequent content divs get bumped to the next line.